# directly quoting %~dp0 does not ignore spaces in file path

Tags: batch-file

i have a script which 3 arguments, two of which are paths. I would like to call it from a .bat file.

```
python myscript.py "%~dp0inputs/" "%~dp0outputs/" "foo"
```

If i call a dummy script that simply prints argv using the above line, i get the expected results, even for paths containing spaces:

```
myscript.py
C:\path\containing spaces\inputs/
C:\path\containing spaces\outputs/
foo
```

however if i use this (ie %~dp0 for argument 1 with nothing else between the quotes):

```
python myscript.py "%~dp0" "%~dp0outputs/" "foo"
```

then it behaves oddly when the path contains spaces:

```
myscript.py
C:\path\containing spaces" C:\path\containing
spaces\outputs/ foo
```

it seems that the quotes have not been processed properly - what have i done wrong?

Comment: It seems like whenever you use `%~dp0` the string needs to end with `/` for being processed properly. What happen if you pass `"%~dp0/"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the quotes are passed into the python script.
And %~dp0 ends with a \ character.

Python figures that \ escapes the double quote - fun.

So, "%~dp0" is passed to the script as

```
"C:\temp\containing spaces\"
```

Python treats that trailing \ as escaping the quote, so it merges the arguments.

It shouldn't do that - but it does.

You can remove the trailing \, or add another.
Either of these works:

```
python myscript.py "%~dp0/" "%~dp0outputs/" "foo"
python myscript.py "%~dp0\" "%~dp0outputs/" "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use **Set** to call your paths within batch. (example below)

```
@echo off

set myscrpt="C:\path\containing spaces\mypythonscript.py"
set mypath1="C:\path\containing spaces\inputs"
set mypath2="C:\path\containing spaces\outputs"

pushd C:\Python27
Python %myscrpt% %mypath1% %mypath2%
pause>NUL
exit
```